# Toggle Corresponding Text Input on Checkbox Change

Tags: jquery, each, str-replace, checked

I have an array of checkboxes that need to display an input when their state is `:checked`.

The checkboxes have different ID's than their corresponding text inputs obviously, so i've attempted to use `.replace` to edit the variable i've set in order to target their corresponding input.

The checkbox parent id's are structured as `icon-metro-NAME` and the text inputs as 'input-NAME`.

Here is my code in sections, and then the entire code after:

```
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {

    var checkbox = jQuery(this);
    var checkboxParentID = jQuery(this).parent().attr('id');
    var inputName = checkboxParentClass.replace(icon-metro, 'input');
```

Attempting to set the `input[type="checkbox"]` as `this` and then find it's parent element ID and set it as `checkboxParentID`. Then I take `checkboxParentID` and replace `icon-metro` with `input` in order to target the corresponding text input field.

```
checkbox.change(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
            jQuery(this).parent('.metro-icon').addClass('active');
            jQuery(inputName).toggle('slow');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parent('.metro-icon').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(inputName).toggle('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

I then detect the `:checked` state of the checkboxes and IF it is checked, I add an `active` class to it's parent `.metro-icon` element. After that I find `:checked` elements corresponding text input `inputName` from my variable and toggle it's visibility. Otherwise, if it is not checked, I remove the `active` class from it's parent and toggle/hide the corresponding text input.

Full code:

```
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {

    var checkbox = jQuery(this);
    var checkboxParentID = jQuery(this).parent().attr('id');
    var inputName = checkboxParentClass.replace(icon-metro, 'input');

    checkbox.change(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
            jQuery(this).parent('.metro-icon').addClass('active');
            jQuery(inputName).toggle('slow');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parent('.metro-icon').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(inputName).toggle('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

I realize it is probably a mess. I am challenging myself to get more advanced with jQuery.

Comment: I've managed to get it almost working using this: http://jsfiddle.net/eFtWh/ but I get a "Object #input-amazon has no method 'toggle' " error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were soooooo close.

You are using jQuery function on a **string**! That was your misstake

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/eFtWh/1/

Instead of doing :

```
inputActualName.toggle('slow');
```

Do :

```
$(inputActualName).toggle('slow');
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I can't believe I was that close yet no cigar.